# element id containing $ character throws exception. How to escape it?

Tags: html

let my expression be ---  #popovertagapplicator-container-m_mid-cAAAm-ZIq209hIFeJe1a7xI2uY-mP-pr$ivate

It gives the error:

Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #popovertagapplicator-container-m_mid-$cAAAm-ZIq209hIFeJe1a7xI2uY-mP-private.

Is there any way to escape $ sign?

Comment: What kind of "expression" should that be? What is the connection to `jquery`?

Comment: when i try to : this.$el.find('#popovertagapplicator-container-m_mid-cAAAm-ZIq209hIFeJe1a7xI2uY-mP-pr$ivate')

it gives me : Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression when expression

Comment: Please add additional details to the question. There is an `edit` link below your question for that. Such details are unreadable in comments.

Comment: The issue simply is that a dollar character is not a valid character in an element id. So this is not an issue with `jquery`, but with your html markup which is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you

```
  <h1>#popovertagapplicator-container-m_mid-cAAAm-ZIq209hIFeJe1a7xI2uY-mP-pr$ivate</h1>

    <script> $('h1').text( $('h1').text().replace(/\$/g, '') ); </script>
```

Comment: Is there any way by which we can escape all the characters which are not a part of https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html which states: ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")."

Comment: var str = "yourstringgoeshere";  var strarray = str.split(','); you can split string by hypen and store in another variable

Answer (score -1):

when i try to : this.$el.find('#popovertagapplicator-container-m_mid-cAAAm-ZIq209hIFeJe1a7xI2uY-mP-pr$ivate')

it gives me : Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression when expression

Comment: This is not an answer. Please delete this.